# When loop completes using freehand drawing using konvajs event?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva

I have made canvas on car image and implemented free hand drawing using KonvaJs .

**what I want is -:**

when free hand completes a **closed loop (any shape)** fill color within closed shape.

*can anyone tell me is there any **event** when closed loop is made*?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no "event" for closed drawing. If you want to detect if a line is closed when the drawing is finished, you can just check the positions of the first and the last points on the line. If they are too close - then you can make a closed shape.

Following [Free drawing demo](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Free_Drawing.html#page-title):

```js
stage.on('mouseup touchend', function () {
  isPaint = false;
  const points = lastLine.points();
  const p1 = {x: points[0], y: points[1]};
  const p2 = {x: points[points.length - 2], y: points[points.length - 1]};
  
  const dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
  if (dist < 10) {
    lastLine.closed(true);
  }
  layer.draw();
});
```

Non react demo: https://jsbin.com/cijobitaza/edit?html,js,output
But you can do something very similar with `react`.

Comment: Thank you for attention !! But I am using Konva.Image for free hand drawing

Comment: Then you can do almost the same. Check the first point and the last one.